# Chip can affect DPF?

Tags: honda, diesel, crv, diesel-particulate-filter

I have a Honda CrV Diesel 2.2L. The DPF light turned on and i lost power. The car has chip. I have twice my car regenerate then I get back the power of my car. Then after 1 week the DPF turn back on. Do you guys think that this Problem comes from the chip or DPF. Honda told me that the DPF is not full. Do i have to take out the chip from the car? Can anybody help me what to do ?

Thank you Best regards H. Mirza

Comment: When you say "chip" is it a remap or a physical plug in "tuning box"?

Comment: It is a box next to the motor. The car has a power 140 PS and now it is 170 PS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the "chip" - I'm 90% certain of it.

You described it in a comment as:

> It is a box next to the motor. The car has a power 140 PS and now it is 170 PS.

The overwhelming majority of these "tuning boxes" are little more than a resistor hooked into the IAT sensor to persuade the car's ECU to overfuel. Sure, it gives you a bit more power (although typically way less than they claim) but it also leads to lots and lots of problems - including quite frequently DPF related problems such as what you're seeing. Bin the "chip" and hope it hasn't done any significant wear to the DPF or anything else expensive.

Comment: The company Honda installed this chip long time ago

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you've installed an aftermarket performance chip into the vehicle which has taken the car from 140 PS to 170 PS.

(**NOTE:** For those who don't know, a "PS" is a power unit known as *pferdestarke*. 1 PS = 0.98632007 HP ... Yah, I had to [look it up](https://www.unitconverters.net/power/pferdestarke-ps-to-horsepower.htm) as well.)

If my assessment of what you've done to your vehicle is correct, then **yes, the chip could be causing the issue with the DPF**. In diesel engines, the easiest way to produce more power is through one of two means (or both):

1. Allow the engine to rev higher
2. Introduce more fuel into the combustion chamber

The first of these will most likely not affect the DPF, however, introducing more fuel certainly can. Most diesel engines run in a *lean burn state*, which means there's more oxygen in the combustion than the engine can use. Diesel engines can run perfectly well here (unlike gasoline engines). When you ad more fuel during any given combustion event, you utilize more of that free oxygen, and thus create more power. The thing is, in the process you also create more particulate matter which the DPF must then clean up, which means it will clog faster. Filter regeneration will clean it up for a period of time, but ultimately it will clog back up.

Bottom line here is, I'd suggest you are in the neighborhood when you are wondering if the chip is causing you this issue. I'd think it most definitely is causing it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! I regenerated twice and the DPF light comes back. Should I try to take the chip out and try?

Comment: @HusseinMirza - I think that's what I'd do :o)

Comment: Hallo paulster2 i disconnected the chip and still did not work. 